# Downgrade Transcrypt version

Tags: java, encryption, transcrypt

I'm using transcrypt for encryption of sensitive files in my project.Right now i'm using version 2.2.0 but I want to downgrade it to version 2.1.0. I tried uninstall it in my project and reinstall lower version but when I type transcrypt --version it always shows 2.2.0. Anyone knows solution?

Comment: How did you downgrade it and how did you get version 2.2 in the first place?

Comment: I cloned it from git and latest version was main 2.2. I don't know how to downgrade it to 2.1

Comment: Their git has tags per version so `git checkout tags/v2.1.0 -b v2.1.0` should switch to that version (in a branch named like the tag, but you can also leave the `-b v2.1.0` out)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.